# Python BS4, Получение информации из тега

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Использую Python 3.8, bs4 и requests библиотеки. У меня возникла тродность: получить информацию из обычного тега проблем не составляет, однако тут тег не обычный, вроде из ангуляра, не уверен. Не могу к нему обратится: перепробовал всё, что знал и нашёл. Прошу помощи. Зарание спасибо! Это мой код получения инфы:

```
def get_date_and_price(link):
    card_html = get_html(rabota_config.URL + link)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(card_html.content, 'html.parser')

    dates = soup.find({"p": "santa-text-black-700 santa-my-20 santa-typo-regular"})
```

```
<p _ngcontent-app-desktop-c254 class="santa-text-black-700 santa-my-20 santa-typo-regular"> Нужная мне информация </p>
```

**Мой вопрос: как к этому обратится, и получить инфу**

Answer (score 0):

Вам осталось сделать последний шаг: `dates.text`, а лучше `dates.text.strip()`.

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
In [2]: html = '''<p _ngcontent-app-desktop-c254 class="santa-text-black-700 santa-my-20 santa-typo-regular"> Нужная мне информация </p>'''
In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
In [4]: dates = soup.find({"p": "santa-text-black-700 santa-my-20 santa-typo-regular"})
In [5]: dates.text.strip()
Out[5]: 'Нужная мне информация'
```